# Grouped bar chart with a surplus bar for baseline condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can do a simple grouped bar chart with error bars that summarizes an experiment with several drugs at several concentrations.

```
ggplot(data=mydata,
 aes(x=factor(drug_concentration),
  y = mean_response,
  fill=drug))+ 
geom_bar(stat="identity",
  position=position_dodge(0.9))+ 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_response-error, 
  ymax=mean_response+error)),
  position=position_dodge(0.9),
  width=0.2)
```

I would also like to add a single separate bar for a baseline condition - sample without drugs (concentration = 0). So the chart would show

- a single column for control
- adjoined columns for drugs at  concentration 1
- adjoined columns for drugs at  concentration 2
- ....

Is it possible to do this with *ggplot2*?

Can error bars be included? I expect there could be problem with dodge and width.

Comment: why do you want a bar, is it not possible to use a vertical line using `geom_vline()`? For error bars you could use `geom_ribbon` perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I don't want to join points by a line that serves to joint the points only. If I were to add a line it would be some regression. But even doing line+ribon does not solve the problem how to include baseline conditions without the drug.

Comment: Maybe you could show a reproducible example. That would make it easier to understand the problem and make suggestions.

Maybe it works to add a new `geom_bar()` & `geom_errorbar()` and specify the `data` argument to the data where the control group is in?